# Can't make recursive call to Http.Request from within end event of Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I want to make an HTTP GET request and then trigger another one as soon as the last one completes. Each request is close to identical (small change to path).

I am having trouble understanding why the following is not working (simplified version):

```
var options = { ... } // host, port etc
var req = request(options, function(res) {

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    db.insert(data);
    options.path = somewhat_new_path;
    req.end(); // doesn't do anything
  });

});

req.end();
```

I know there are many libraries and so on for sequencing asynchronous code, but I would really like to understand why I can't achieve an asynchronous loop in this way.

Comment: Do you want to know why `req.end();` inside `res.on` is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.end()` finishes the request. Response won't start coming until you finish the request. Hence `req.end()` inside `res.on('end',function(){})` doesn't make any sense.

If you want to make another request with some other path you can do something like:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = { ... } // host, port etc

makeRequest(options, function() {
  db.insert(data);
  options.path = somewhat_new_path;
  makeRequest(options, function() { //this will make a recursive synchronous call
    db.insert(data);
  });
});

options.path = another_path;
makeRequest(options, function() {  //this will make a asynchronous call
  db.insert(data);
});

var makeRequest = function(options, callback) {
  http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data+=chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', callback);
  }).end();
}
```

Comment: I know that req.end() finishes request but I call it outside first - so the request is triggered. Then when the Response's end event is triggered I just want to call it again. Can you explain in more detail why that won't work?

Comment: @DanielC Yes, it is triggered outside. But same request cannot be triggered twice. You'll have to make another `http.request`.

Comment: ok. thanks. I see now that I have to wrap it in a function and pass that as the callback.